# ReadOnly XAML propery

Tags: wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I have a UserControl called GridContainer, and in the XAML I declared a DataGrid control. I want to be able to access this DataGrid from XAML when used within a Window:

```
<local:GridContainer>
   <local:GridContainer.MyDataGrid>
       .
       .
       .
   <local:GridContainer.MyDataGrid>
</local:GridContainer>
```

How do I declare a dependency property to access my nested DataGrid within my UserControl?

Comment: You should in general not expose controls as properties, but forward the properties on the control.

Comment: But even in such a case, how would you expose a property of an existing control using a Dependency property?

Comment: just to make sure, you have a user control defined in XAML which have properties and you want to know how to make those properties exposed as dependency properties ?

Comment: Yes, so my UserControl has a special type of DataGrid within it, and this DataGrid has a property called TableView. How can I expose TablweView so I can access it in XAML?

Answer (score 0):

Well i don't know what exactly is you problem, but i will suggest a solution non the less. Why can't you go to the UserControl code behind file and put there normal Dependency Property definitions. visual studio has a snippet that can help you a lot in that area.